# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): x, y, fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am creating a ggplot grouped barplot with error bars for a school assignment. I'm quite new to ggplot, however the assignment stipulates that I must use ggplot for this plot. However I keep getting an error saying "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): x, y, fill". How do I fix this? Apologies in advance for the messiness of my data.

```
drought = read.csv("drought_elevation.csv")
drought
#Packages
> drought = read.csv("drought_elevation.csv")
> drought
            spec elevation   treat height
1   A. australis       low    ctrl   24.9
2   A. australis       low    ctrl   25.3
3   A. australis       low    ctrl   25.7
4   A. australis       low    ctrl   33.0
5   A. australis       low    ctrl   31.2
6   A. australis       low    ctrl   25.5
7   A. australis       low    ctrl   20.8
8   A. australis       low    ctrl   28.6
9   A. australis       low    ctrl   26.8
10  A. australis       low    ctrl   24.5
11     P. totara       low    ctrl   34.5
12     P. totara       low    ctrl   29.2
13     P. totara       low    ctrl   27.7
14     P. totara       low    ctrl   25.7
15     P. totara       low    ctrl   34.1
16     P. totara       low    ctrl   28.9
17     P. totara       low    ctrl   34.1
18     P. totara       low    ctrl   22.8
19     P. totara       low    ctrl   39.9
20     P. totara       low    ctrl   33.9
21       B. tawa       low    ctrl   44.7
22       B. tawa       low    ctrl   42.5
23       B. tawa       low    ctrl   37.9
24       B. tawa       low    ctrl   41.6
25       B. tawa       low    ctrl   39.5
26       B. tawa       low    ctrl   41.3
27       B. tawa       low    ctrl   37.5
28       B. tawa       low    ctrl   34.2
29       B. tawa       low    ctrl   39.7
30       B. tawa       low    ctrl   43.4
31  A. australis       mid    ctrl   26.3
32  A. australis       mid    ctrl   16.0
33  A. australis       mid    ctrl   25.8
34  A. australis       mid    ctrl   15.7
35  A. australis       mid    ctrl   26.3
36  A. australis       mid    ctrl   25.7
37  A. australis       mid    ctrl   17.9
38  A. australis       mid    ctrl   15.4
39  A. australis       mid    ctrl   22.3
40  A. australis       mid    ctrl   29.6
41     P. totara       mid    ctrl   22.4
42     P. totara       mid    ctrl   22.0
43     P. totara       mid    ctrl   31.3
44     P. totara       mid    ctrl   27.0
45     P. totara       mid    ctrl   29.6
46     P. totara       mid    ctrl   27.2
47     P. totara       mid    ctrl   20.0
48     P. totara       mid    ctrl   30.5
49     P. totara       mid    ctrl   24.7
50     P. totara       mid    ctrl   20.8
51       B. tawa       mid    ctrl   27.8
52       B. tawa       mid    ctrl   32.6
53       B. tawa       mid    ctrl   29.1
54       B. tawa       mid    ctrl   26.5
55       B. tawa       mid    ctrl   31.2
56       B. tawa       mid    ctrl   29.3
57       B. tawa       mid    ctrl   25.4
58       B. tawa       mid    ctrl   26.5
59       B. tawa       mid    ctrl   32.4
60       B. tawa       mid    ctrl   33.5
61  A. australis      high    ctrl   19.1
62  A. australis      high    ctrl   21.2
63  A. australis      high    ctrl   15.0
64  A. australis      high    ctrl   10.9
65  A. australis      high    ctrl   15.5
66  A. australis      high    ctrl   10.0
67  A. australis      high    ctrl    6.4
68  A. australis      high    ctrl   18.4
69  A. australis      high    ctrl   12.6
70  A. australis      high    ctrl   16.6
71     P. totara      high    ctrl   23.3
72     P. totara      high    ctrl   19.1
73     P. totara      high    ctrl   14.6
74     P. totara      high    ctrl   20.0
75     P. totara      high    ctrl   21.6
76     P. totara      high    ctrl   23.5
77     P. totara      high    ctrl   14.7
78     P. totara      high    ctrl   23.9
79     P. totara      high    ctrl   21.7
80     P. totara      high    ctrl   19.6
81       B. tawa      high    ctrl   25.6
82       B. tawa      high    ctrl   16.9
83       B. tawa      high    ctrl   34.8
84       B. tawa      high    ctrl   32.4
85       B. tawa      high    ctrl   20.3
86       B. tawa      high    ctrl   17.4
87       B. tawa      high    ctrl   34.4
88       B. tawa      high    ctrl   25.5
89       B. tawa      high    ctrl   25.0
90       B. tawa      high    ctrl   25.9
91  A. australis       low drought   21.1
92  A. australis       low drought   14.9
93  A. australis       low drought    9.3
94  A. australis       low drought   18.9
95  A. australis       low drought   22.9
96  A. australis       low drought   21.2
97  A. australis       low drought   14.4
98  A. australis       low drought   24.1
99  A. australis       low drought   19.0
100 A. australis       low drought    8.8
101    P. totara       low drought   18.2
102    P. totara       low drought   24.1
103    P. totara       low drought   20.2
104    P. totara       low drought   17.9
105    P. totara       low drought   27.6
106    P. totara       low drought   15.9
107    P. totara       low drought   27.3
108    P. totara       low drought   22.1
109    P. totara       low drought   26.6
110    P. totara       low drought   29.2
111      B. tawa       low drought   32.8
112      B. tawa       low drought   25.9
113      B. tawa       low drought   28.7
114      B. tawa       low drought   34.3
115      B. tawa       low drought   42.5
116      B. tawa       low drought   33.0
117      B. tawa       low drought   27.2
118      B. tawa       low drought   19.9
119      B. tawa       low drought   25.8
120      B. tawa       low drought   31.1
121 A. australis       mid drought   18.7
122 A. australis       mid drought   14.9
123 A. australis       mid drought   14.9
124 A. australis       mid drought   16.2
125 A. australis       mid drought    7.7
126 A. australis       mid drought   11.0
127 A. australis       mid drought    8.2
128 A. australis       mid drought   25.9
129 A. australis       mid drought   21.3
130 A. australis       mid drought    1.7
131    P. totara       mid drought   12.1
132    P. totara       mid drought   19.9
133    P. totara       mid drought   12.8
134    P. totara       mid drought   28.1
135    P. totara       mid drought   19.6
136    P. totara       mid drought   19.2
137    P. totara       mid drought   15.7
138    P. totara       mid drought   25.3
139    P. totara       mid drought   12.5
140    P. totara       mid drought   23.6
141      B. tawa       mid drought   20.4
142      B. tawa       mid drought   24.5
143      B. tawa       mid drought   22.3
144      B. tawa       mid drought   24.6
145      B. tawa       mid drought   22.0
146      B. tawa       mid drought   18.9
147      B. tawa       mid drought   17.9
148      B. tawa       mid drought   23.0
149      B. tawa       mid drought   24.8
150      B. tawa       mid drought   23.7
151 A. australis      high drought    3.4
152 A. australis      high drought   11.9
153 A. australis      high drought    7.9
154 A. australis      high drought    5.3
155 A. australis      high drought    6.1
156 A. australis      high drought    7.1
157 A. australis      high drought    7.4
158 A. australis      high drought    8.2
159 A. australis      high drought    4.3
160 A. australis      high drought    0.6
161    P. totara      high drought   14.6
162    P. totara      high drought   14.4
163    P. totara      high drought    9.5
164    P. totara      high drought    9.5
165    P. totara      high drought   19.5
166    P. totara      high drought    4.3
167    P. totara      high drought    9.2
168    P. totara      high drought   13.5
169    P. totara      high drought   14.3
170    P. totara      high drought   20.6
171      B. tawa      high drought   19.2
172      B. tawa      high drought   19.8
173      B. tawa      high drought   15.5
174      B. tawa      high drought   18.4
175      B. tawa      high drought   16.1
176      B. tawa      high drought   18.9
177      B. tawa      high drought   23.1
178      B. tawa      high drought   20.0
179      B. tawa      high drought    8.7
180      B. tawa      high drought   25.4
> #Packages
> library(ggplot2)
> library(plyr)
> library(reshape2)
> library(dplyr)
> 
> #Elevations
> lowh = drought[drought$elevation %in% c("low"), ]
> midh = drought[drought$elevation %in% c("mid"), ]
> highh = drought[drought$elevation %in% c("high"), ]
> 
> 
> #Se function
> se <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) { 
+   if (na.rm) { 
+     sqrt(var(x, na.rm = T)/length(na.omit(x))) 
+   } else { 
+     if (any(is.na(sqrt(var(x)/length(x))))) stop("There are NAs in the data!")
+     sqrt(var(x)/length(x))
+   }
+ }
> dat1 <- group_by(.data = lowh, treat, spec) %>%
+   summarise(height_aver = mean(height, na.rm = T),
+             se.pos = mean(height, na.rm = T) + se(height, na.rm = T),
+             se.neg = mean(height, na.rm = T) - se(height, na.rm = T))
> dat1 <- dat1[order(dat1$spec), ]
> dat1
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   treat [2]
    treat         spec height_aver   se.pos   se.neg
   <fctr>       <fctr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1    ctrl A. australis       26.63 27.73956 25.52044
2 drought A. australis       17.46 19.16901 15.75099
3    ctrl      B. tawa       40.23 41.22029 39.23971
4 drought      B. tawa       30.12 32.05975 28.18025
5    ctrl    P. totara       31.08 32.68864 29.47136
6 drought    P. totara       22.91 24.40179 21.41821
> 
> wide <- acast(dat1, treat ~ spec, value.var = "height_aver")
> 
> ####Actual plot####
> low <- ggplot(wide, aes(x = spec, y = height, fill = treat))
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class matrix
> 
> cleanup = theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))
> 
> p1= (low + cleanup + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 35)) 
+      + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") 
+      + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) 
+      + xlab("Species") 
+      + ylab("Seedling height (cm)") 
+      + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009933", "#FFcc66"), name = "Treatment") 
+      + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lowh$height-se, ymax=lowh$height+se), position = "dodge"))
> p1
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (6): x, y, fill
> dev.off()
```

Comment: Did you happen to notice the earlier error creating `low`? Maybe fix that first? (Hint: acast returns a matrix, you don't want that. Maybe try dcast instead? Or avoid reshape2 entirely and use spread() from tidyr)

Comment: You're right I somehow missed that! I've changed it to dcast and that problem appears to have gone away however the original aesthetics error still remains

Comment: Your data (x,y) has length 6 but lowh$height has length 60

Comment: there are few other issues with the code here, it will be helpful to post a modified version of code you are working on, for example here you haven't passed any arguments when making a call to function ``se``.